# Can't run EXE4j with OpenJDK 12

Tags: exe4j

I am trying to use EXE4j version version 6.0.2 with OpenJDK version 12.0.2. However when I try to compile (or open EXE4j) I get

```
  [exe4j] No JVM could be found on your system.
    [exe4j] Please define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME
    [exe4j] to point to an installed 64-bit JDK or JRE or download a JRE from 
    www.java.com.
```

I already have the environment folders for EXE4J_JAVA_HOME and JAVA_HOME pointing to the base of the JDK. I also added the JDK\bin folder to my path.

Does EXE4j only work with certain versions of Java?

Comment: On what platform are you trying to run exe4j? On Windows, a suitable JRE is packaged. On other platforms, you would need a Java 8 JRE.

Comment: I'm running on windows yes. Where is the jre packged in the zip file?

Comment: Sorry, exe4j indeed does not bundle a JRE. The exe4j wizard in the current version does not work with Java 12, but it will in the next version (7.0) that is planned to be released in a couple of weeks.